# Merge multiple (+3) lists of dicts depending on a Unique key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

Context: I use multiple providers that have different `prices` for the same products (altogether 19200 products -> multiple lists with each 19200 products inside). I fetch the data from lets say `3 API's`, which leaves me with 3 lists of dicts like the following:

```
allLists=[
    [{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"4.44","price2":"","price3":""}, {dict2},{dict3},..],
    [{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"","price2":"3.44","price3":""},{dict2},{dict3},..],
    [{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"","price2":"","price3":"5.43"},{dict2},{dict3},..],
]
```

`market_hash_name` is the unique identifier for a product. To store these to my database, I now need a `resultList` which contains all the products and also the prices from all providers.

so the result should look like this: (note the merged prices)

```
[{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"4.44","price2":"3.44","price3":"5.43"},{dict2},{dict3},..]
```

I am relatively new to python, so how could I achieve this in relatively short time? Currently it takes about 30 seconds, which is a bit too long imo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please show the code you are currently using?

Comment: I unfornuately dont have it anymore, but i just iterated over each list, checking, if any of the dicts inside contains the `market_hash_name`, then saving the price of this product and assigning it to a `result_product`

Comment: ok, how big is your full dataset?

Comment: because there are in total 19200 products that are compared, the result-dataset will contain 19200. After fetching each api, I have `n` lists with 19200 items each -> `n * 19200`

Answer (score 1):

itertools is a possibility. It has the [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function that can be used to treat the list of lists as a single iterable, and also the [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function.

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

allLists=[
    [{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"4.44","price2":"","price3":""},],
    [{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"","price2":"3.44","price3":""},],
    [{"market_hash_name":"ak-redline","category":"rifle","condition":"fn","price1":"","price2":"","price3":"5.43"},],
]

finalList = []

# Group the elements of the lists by the 'market_hash_name' value
for k, g in groupby(chain(*allLists), key=lambda a: a['market_hash_name']):
  # k is the string value of the 'market_hash_name' key
  # g is a generator that will return all dictionaries that have k as the market_hash_name

  matches = list(g)
  
  ##############
  #Finish logic to build entries for finalList here
  ##############
```

There are likely more elegant/efficient solutions out there but that could get you started

Comment: Big thanks for the response, it works in a small example and I kind of understand it now. I will try it out in the project tomorrow and see, how it does there.

Comment: Okay so i'm not sure, if this works, when each list in `allLists` would contain two or more `dicts`